# Error "Operand of * must be a pointer" al crear puntero con malloc y usarlo en un FOR

Tags: c

Estoy probando un ejemplo del libro "Understanding and using Pointers" que tiene este código:

```
int main()
{
    char *pc = (char*)malloc(6);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        *pc[i] = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

En teoría, debería funcionar, pero me aparece el error:

> Operand of * must be a pointer.

¿Pueden decirme qué hay de malo? Estoy usando Visual Studio 2015 Community.

Comment: Otro detalle malo del código además de lo que te indiquen es que deberías incluir `free` para liberar la memoria reservada por `malloc`. No hay que perder las buenas costumbres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error está en que para hacer referencia a la variable pc dentro del bucle ya no tienes que utilizar el símbolo del puntero.

```
pc[i] = 0;
```

De esa forma inicializas la memoria.

Si lo que quieres es copiar el carácter 0, añade comillas simples:

```
pc[i] = '0';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. No sé por qué está en el libro así.

Comment: Será una errata